# Shortcut to display scale from cache in qgis print composter

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

When loading a map in the print composer I always click on the main area where the map displays, then click on 'set to map canvas extent'. Then I adjust the scale as I need. This is all fine.

How do I pick up the scale (e.g. 4000) and have this value automatically inserted into a different part of the printing template as follows?

> Scale 1:4000 @ A3

At the moment I have to type the scale by hand every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "numeric" type scalebar and voila:

[image]